# How to disable service workers in Safari?

Tags: safari

Is there a way to disable Service Workers completely in Safari (as a user)?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for Safari 12.0.3, the *experimental* feature set is different in different Safari versions.

Enable the Safari developer menu. Safari Preferences > "Advanced" pref pane > "Show Develop menu in menu bar" checkbox at the bottom.

Then, in Develop menu, go to "Experimental Features" menu item and disable "Service Workers" in the sub menu.

[image]