# How to disable service workers in Safari 12.1? (Mac)

Tags: mac, safari

In Safari 12.1 Service workers can’t be disabled anymore via Develop > Experimental Features. I guess it’s not an experimental feature anymore.

Is there any other way to disable them? Sometimes the whatsapp service worker seems to have a hiccup and uses 100% cpu utilization.

earlier solution for safari versions pre 12.1:
[How to disable service workers in Safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352812/how-to-disable-service-workers-in-safari)

Comment: I don't have anything in there I can test, but the menu item for Service Workers is now directly above that for Experimental Features - maybe each is individually [un]checkable? https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC5n9.png

Comment: Unfortunately its not [un]checkable. The item shows a list of service workers of your open tabs (for example youtube and whatsapp) and upon click on one of the workers, the developer tools open with the chosen service worker. I didn't find anything helpful in the developer tools either

Answer (score 4):

You can try to turn off the feature via the `Debug` menu.  For me, using Safari 12.1.1, It is listed under

`Debug` -> `WebKit Internal Features` -> `Service Workers`

Note that I am referring to the internal `Debug` menu, and not the `Developer` menu.  The `Debug` menu is activated by writing the key `IncludeInternalDebugMenu`  into Safari preferences (e.g. `defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1` -- under Mojave, you will have to grant Full Disk Access to Terminal.app first; otherwise the setting will not take.)

I'm not sure if this persists across browser restarts, though.

Answer (score 1):

As I cannot add a comment, I must submit it as an answer.

@vykor answer is good.

There needs to be one more step at the end.

I had to restart the browser too for the `Debug` menu to appear.

It did not appear automatically as the `Developer` menu.
I have Mojave + Safari 12.1.1